# Thinking of $\int f(x) g(nx) dx$ as an integral with respect to the measure $g(nx)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I am trying to answer the following question: Let $g$ be a bounded lebesgue measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{n} \int_I g(nx) dx = 0$ for all intervals $I \subset [0,1]$. Suppose $f \in L^1([0,1])$. Show $\lim_{n} \int_0^1 f(x) g(nx) dx = 0$.

I have the idea that I can treat $g(nx)$ as a radon nikodym derivative, use the jordan decomposition to split $g(nx)dx$ into two nonnegative measures, and show that those assign $0$ mass to the unit interval as $n$ goes to infinity. In this way the desired integral would also tend to $0$. But, I have not been able to properly flesh out the details and would like some help.

The reason I want to use the jordan decomposition to split the measure is so that I can use theorems requiring nonnegative functions like Fatou's lemma to show convergence. I am aware that there are proofs of this problem using other methods but I specifically want to use the idea above for practicing usage of radon nikodym.

Comment: Presumably we have a restriction on $f$?  Possibly $f \in L^1[0,1]$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, my bad. The problem says exactly that. I will edit the question.

Comment: What is the role of $n$  in $g(nx)$?

Comment: The limits are all taken over $n$. I was also told it would be good to think about this problem if you take $g$ to be something like $sin(n\pi x)$ to get some intuition.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_I g(nx)\, dx = 0$ for all intervals $I \subset [0,1]$,we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f(x)g(nx)\,dx=0$$
for any step function $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\chi_{I_k}$ where $I_k\subset[0,1]$ is an interval.

Now suppose $f\in L^1$. Since step functions are dense in $L^1$, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can write $f=f_1+f_2$ where $f_1$ is a step function and $\int_0^1|f_2|\,dx<\epsilon$. Using what we've proven for step functions and the boundedness of $g$ gives that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f(x)g(nx)\,dx=0.$$

Comment: I'm trying to understand where radon nikodym comes in. When you say $L^1$ do you mean $L^1([0,1], \mu)$, where maybe $\mu$ is the measure $g(nx)dx$ converges to (since space of borel measures is weak star compact this limit exists).

Comment: @user9781778 When I say $L^1$ I mean $L^1([0,1],\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.  Btw, I can't see what has this problem to do with Radon-Nikodym.

Comment: I'm just saying since $g(nx)$ is a bounded measurable function for each $n$, we can think of them as radon nikodym derivatives. And my assessment is that if we integrate $f$ against those measures, we should get $0$ as $n$ increases since I think the limit assumption we're given can be thought of as saying that the measures eventually pick up no mass on the unit interval.

Comment: @user9781778 I see. In my opinion, you can understand this problem in this way. But to **prove** it, it may not be an efficient thought.  I've proved your problem, using the Lebesgue theory. Hopefully you can understand it.

Comment: Oh I totally get what you have written; thanks. I think maybe the first two lines can be used to prove it the way I am thinking about if I can properly justify passing the limit through the integral.